# O(n) algorithm to check if a string is the lexicographically smallest rotation?

Tags: algorithm, rotation

There are a few linear time algorithms that can identify a lexicoraphically minimal rotation of a string, but they are rather complicated and involved.
Does the simpler problem of checking whether a given, specific rotation is a minimal one have a simpler, more intuitive O(n) algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a string is the minimum among all its rotations can be verified in O(n):

- Use a second index that runs ahead of a first index to compare characters.
- When they are the same character, increase both indices.
- When the second character is less than the first character, return false -- the string does not represent a minimal rotation.
- When the second character is greater than the first character, reset the first index to 0.
- Repeat this process until the first index has reached the end of the string, or the second index has wrapped around for a second iteration and the first index has been reset (due to the previous bullet point).
- Return true when this loop ends.

This means the second index may make at most two scans over the string, giving it a O(n) complexity.

Here is a little snippet that implements the algorithm in JavaScript. It interactively outputs false/true as you enter a string input:

```js
function isMinimalRotation(s) {
    let i = 0;
    for (let j = 1; i % s.length > 0 || j < s.length; j++) {
        let ch = s[j % s.length];
        if (ch < s[i]) return false;
        i = ch > s[i] ? 0 : i + 1;
    }
    return true;
}

// I/O Handling

const [input, span] = document.querySelectorAll("input, span");
const refresh = () => span.textContent = isMinimalRotation(input.value);
input.addEventListener("input", refresh);
refresh();
```

```html
String input: <input value="1112311231124"><br>
Is minimal rotation?: <span></span>
```

The meaning of the `for` loop condition is that the loop should exit when `j` has iterated all elements at least once, **and** `i` has been reset to 0, or has also iterated all elements (`i == s.length`). As one of  these two `i` values is guaranteed to occur during `j`'s second iteration of the array, the loop is guaranteed to end before `j` makes a third iteration.

In Python you could code it like this:

```py
def is_minimal_rotation(s):
    i = 0
    n = len(s)
    for j in range(1, n*2):
        ch = s[j % n]
        if ch < s[i]:
            return False
        i = 0 if ch > s[i] else i + 1
        if i in (0, n) and j >= n:
            return True
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a basically a simplification of something I came up with as well. Mine does almost the same thing but was overly complicated so I got stuck proving it is really O(n) and completes correctly, this is easier to show!

Comment: I guess that in the for loop you meant to check:
`**j** % s.length > 0 || **i** < s.length` is that correct?
is it enough to check j<s.length+1 ?

Comment: No, I really meant it like I wrote it. It is not enough to check `j < s.length + 1`. Is there a case where the proposed algorithm is not giving the correct result?

Comment: it gives the correct result, but it seems to work with `j<s.length+1` which means going over the input only once (plus checking the first character) rather than going over it twice.
Is that wrong? I can't think of the input case that needs it to wrap around past the first character

Comment: I'm not sure which variation of the code you have in mind. What would you change to have that "plus checking the first character"? Does your idea work with input `12312`?

Comment: Expanding on that:

For both of the `||` conditions to be false and the loop to terminate, `i >=s.length` and `j%s.length == 0` which I guess means that j is back on 0 and doesn't continue to wrap around further.

Comment: I added a paragraph to my answer. Hope that better clarifies the idea behind the `for` loop condition.

Comment: I'm not sure of the all the syntax of javascript.

I tried this code in python that I believe does work on 12312 but that my be a fluke:

`       i = 0
        k = len(s)
        while i < k:
          for j in range(1,k):
            if s[j%k)] < s[i]: return False
            if s[j%k] > s[i]: i=0
            else: i += 1
          return True
`

Comment: I added a Python version to my answer.

Comment: thanks! I understood the answer, I was thinking it was possible to do it more efficiently without having to complete the second loop over the input. But that is not correct, I just tested it on a few special cases that it happened to work. I have marked this as the accepted answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248597/discussion-between-david-pellow-and-trincot).